# Can a Twitter account have multiple users contributing?

Tags: twitter, account-management, user-accounts

We have a Twitter account for our company but want other staff members to contribute to its feed. Is this possible?

Comment: One way is to use [TweetDeck Teams](https://blog.twitter.com/2015/introducing-tweetdeck-teams).

Answer (score 1):

Of course. There are many solutions out there that make this easy.

The easiest of course is just giving each staff member the password, but that has the downside of not being able to track who posted what. Plus you'd have to change the password when staff members change.

I've usually got around this by using [HootSuite](https://hootsuite.com/). I haven't used it recently so some of this may have changed, but the general way it works is:

- you create a 'master account' on HootSuite, and connect it to your Twitter account(s)
- you create 'team member' accounts, and choose who has access to what (this can be useful if you have multiple Twitter accounts, Facebook pages etc. and want different people to have access to different accounts)
- each team member then posts or schedules their tweets by logging in to their HootSuite account (from the web, or from the mobile app)

This way you can see who posts what, and you can easily remove or add access as you require.

In this scenario, you don't give out the 'master account' password for HootSuite unless you want someone to be able to manage who has access (eg. perhaps someone from HR). Also, you never need to give out the Twitter account password - keep that private as whoever has it can disconnect HootSuite from the account at any time.

You could also look at [TweetDeck teams](https://blog.twitter.com/2015/introducing-tweetdeck-teams) as mentioned in the comments by [Bookend](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/79865/bookend), which I believe works in a similar way (although I haven't used it myself). There are other options out there too, like [Buffer](https://buffer.com), all offering slightly different features.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are you happy to give them all the password.

Or you might be able to create away of doing it by having them send emails, and using IFTTT.